# Blender 2.79 white matcap issue in sculpt mode

Tags: matcaps

I'm currently working on a character and I just saw that the ears of the character was not matching on each side. So, I decide to use Symmetrize and it did not work.

I try every possible way to get the 2 side the same but it was just not working. I randomly, out of nowhere change the matcap to the clay and the character ears became identical!!!! I don't know how did that happened, but the white matcap on this mesh is broken!

I would need to know if its an issue or not.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: I think it's just the shading being different on the white matcap.  I don't think the geometry changed with the red matcap.  As a side note, that ear looks way too small for the size of the head.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just decide to use another shading.... Also the picture was in orthographic, is thats still a problem?